# UART decoding via picoscope SDK

Tags: c, uart, decoding

I'm working to use picoscope APIs for programming picoscope 2205a, and I need to decode standard UART protocol, but I couldn't find any API in picoscope SDK (ps2000aApi.h) for decoding UART frame.
picoscope API functions only provide the capability of setting up the scope and capturing data.
is there a way for UART decoding?
Thank you,

Comment: I would expect that the SDK comes with some tutorials and  examples to look at. What did you find, and why does it not help you?

Comment: I look to SDK tutorials and I prepared example for capturing data, but as I saied picoscope API functions only provide the capability of setting up the scope and capturing data, no APIs for UART decoding

Comment: So if you find that the documentation and the API do not provide a ready-made UART decoder, you need to write your own. This is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to mention here is that the PicoScope software application already comes with support for UART decoding (this includes exporting a decoded table of UART frames into a csv file) so I recommend checking if this fulfils any of your requirements. i.e. would it be adequate for your application to take a csv containing a sequence of UART frames as an input or does it need to decode in real time?

See here for more information on PicoScope's software support of UART decoding: https://www.picotech.com/library/oscilloscopes/rs-232-serial-protocol-decoding

The fact that you are talking about writing your own application using the SDK leads me to presume that it's not adequate but it's worth covering that base.

The second point to make is that the PicoScope API provides hooks to setup a capturing configuration (i.e. samples/s, vertical ranges, triggering on voltage transitions etc) but it doesn't currently provide hooks to set decoding configurations or access decoded frames.

This ultimately means you will have to roll your own UART decoding functionality within your application. In order to do this you will need to:

1. Pull analog sampled data off the device. There is comprehensive help online (on the PicoScope website and forums) in order to guide you through this process. This PicoScope 2000 programmer's guide is a good start if you are using the 2205A: https://www.picotech.com/download/manuals/picoscope-2000-series-programmers-guide.pdf.
2. Once you have the analog sampled data you are then ultimately looking to convert a bit pattern from the signal at a given bit rate. Here's a good resource on how a UART signal is broken down into it's constituent parts: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/501854

Hope that helps!